# Regarding Sentence Formation?

Tags: grammar, sentence, syntactic-analysis

I generally face problem in sentence structure .

Which one is correct :-

- Mainly he does this .
- He mainly does this .
- He does mainly this .
- He does this mainly .

All the above sentences seem to be correct and carry same meaning

I being a non native speaker of English generally face this problem .

Is there any rule regarding this problem which not only applies to this particular example but for all such similar examples ?

Comment: A few of them may mean the same thing in effect. However, all of them are **not** of the same meaning.

Comment: @Kris Which one should I treat as most appropriate ?

Comment: There are similar/related previous posts on ELU. A search may be of help. Good Luck.

Comment: All are grammatical and acceptable.

Comment: @Kris Any keyword for what I should search for ?

Comment: See also [ell.se]

Comment: The partial focusing modifier "mainly" focuses here on what he does. I think most people would say that they assert the same proposition, i.e. that he doesn't do anything else to the same extent as he does "this".

Comment: @BillJ Are all the sentences correct then ?

Comment: Yes, they are fine.

Comment: Adverbial quantifiers like _mainly_ can go before the beginning of any constituent, or at the end of the sentence. In a short sentence like the example, every niche  meets this requirement. In a longer sentence there would be fewer niches, since the constituents would be longer.

Comment: @JohnLawler So in long sentences , we would have to use mainly either at start or at end ?

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. The start or the end is usually OK, but right before the constituent that you mean to emphasize is the safest place.

Comment: too far in the weeds; score and keep it moving!  make your point, polish it off, wash, rinse, repeat ... concern with hairy details that return little value is a long road to nowhere.   there are bigger fish to fry, please believe me ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a sentence more specific than 'He does this', the position of 'mainly' could affect the meaning.

(As his occupation) he mainly sells antiques (but  also writes for the local newspaper).

(In his shop) he sells mainly antiques (but also modern ceramics).

Comment: So do all the sentences carry different meanings or are same ?

Comment: I said that the position of 'mainly' _could_ affect the meaning (depending what the sentence is), not that all your sentences meant something different.